# How to pass form data as instance in Django?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views, django-forms

**info**: I am trying to make an app like monthly instalment payment of items(property or etc).

I want when I fill out the customer form and select the product, I have to submit the payment form along with it and that payment will be linked to that customer. So in order to do this work, I have created a `CustomerPayment` model. I don't know how the **models** should be designed to do this.

**Problem** I am trying to submit the customer payment along with the customer form but my form is not submitted it's redirect me to back on form. i don't know how can i pass the both form data as instances of **CustomerPayment** `(customer=customer & payment=payment)`.

**Example**:

[image]

models.py

```
class Customer(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    phone = models.CharField(max_length=11, blank=True)

class Payment(models.Model):
    collect_by = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.SET_NULL)
    customer = models.ForeignKey(Customer, on_delete=models.SET_NULL)
    datetime = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    amount = models.DecimalField(default=0)
    remaining = models.DecimalField(default=0)
```

**views.py**

```
def order_form(request):

    customer_form = CustomerForm(request.POST)
    payment_form = PaymentForm(request.POST)

    if request.method == 'POST':

        if customer_form.is_valid() and payment_form.is_valid():
            customer = customer_form.instance.sales_men = request.user
            customer.save(commit=False)

            payment = payment_form.instance.collect_by = request.user
            payment.instance.customer = customer
            payment.save(commit=False)

            return redirect('/')

    context = {
        'customer_form': customer_form,
        'payment_form': payment_form,
    }
    return render(request, "payment/payment_create.html", context)
```

Comment: I feel like a customer makes a payment, not multiple customers (that may be wrong) so you could just have the FK to customer on the `Payment` and only have 2 models.

Comment: Yeah you are write! i want to get multiple or one payment from one customer. i mean multiple payments along with the single customer. so do you mean i need to add `Payment` model FK in Customer model?

Comment: Move the `customer` FK from the `CustomerPayment` to the `Payment` model and remove the `CustomerPayment` model.

Comment: Please take a look i have to update the payment Model and `order` function also in views...

Comment: Dear can you tell me how can i pass that customer Instance @markwalker_

Comment: @markwalker_ Dear can i ask you something...?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you want to do in your view is something like this;

```
def order_form(request):

    customer_form = CustomerForm()
    payment_form = PaymentForm()

    if request.method == 'POST':
        customer_form = CustomerForm(request.POST)
        payment_form = PaymentForm(request.POST)

        if customer_form.is_valid() and payment_form.is_valid():
            customer = customer.save(commit=False)
            customer.sales_men = request.user
            customer.save()

            payment = payment_form.save(commit=False)
            payment.collect_by = request.user
            payment.customer = customer
            payment.save()

            return redirect('/')

    context = {
        'customer_form': customer_form,
        'payment_form': payment_form,
    }
    return render(request, "payment/payment_create.html", context)
```

If all the `Customer` model has is a name and phone number, you should consider moving that data on to the `Payment`. If nothing else, it'd simplify what you're doing in this view.

You've also got a FK on the `Customer` and a FK on the `Payment` both pointing to the same `User`. It feels like this would be simpler if a `Payment` had a FK to a `User`.

The `User` model already holds a name, so you might be able to drop the `Customer` model, of it there's data still needed make a `Profile` model which has a `user = models.OneToOneField()`. Then `request.user.profile` would give you a user profile for extra data

Comment: Dear it's looks like that customer pay me just one time when i add new customer i can add a one payment from this customer but  i want to collect multiple payments from this customer.

Comment: Then surely they just fill in the forms again to make another payment?